# View specific pdf version from git repository with linux application

Tags: tools, revision-control, git

Are there any Linux programs that can open specific versions of a pdf file under revision control with git.

I have been using subversion for version control with my latex documents, but I am giving git a try now. I have been using kdesvn as a gui; in the log history view, selecting a specific revision, one can right click on a pdf file committed and `cat this version'. The corresponding revision of the pdf file is opened in a pdf viewer.

Is there a git revision history viewer for linux which can do the same? I have tried gitk, gitg, qgit, git-cola, git-eye, giggle, smartgit and gitextension with no luck (at least I have not figured out how to do it in any of these). Of the one's that show anything of a pdf file the output is useless. Some can open the pdf with an external application, but only the most recent version. Some have the option to save a specific version of a pdf file; typically I want to look over a file and see how it looked, I don't need to save it.

I know this can be done from the command line, I'm asking specifically about a gui for it. Is there something I missed in the programs mentioned above, or one I missed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about manipulation of pdf files (and not TeX/LaTeX manipulation of them) not creation of pdf from Tex sources

Comment: True, but it is about using git as a version control tool for latex documents, about which there have been questions here before - which is why I thought to ask here.

Comment: I have a shell script that does exactly this. I'll post details when I have time. I think that this question is of sufficient general interest to people using latex so I have voted against closing it.

Comment: @Guido I think that this is actually a latex question. At least the way that I solve this is using latex:)

Comment: A simple `git checkout REVISION && latekmk file -pdf && evince file.pdf && git checkout HEAD` should do what you want, or not?

Comment: I have a bash script for doing this. The main feature that it adds over @Habi's answer is that it adds a banner down the side of each page from the commit message. (It also serves as a front-end to [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff).) I have only used/tested it on macosx. I have added some (very minimal) documentation and made it accessible from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AndrewsBucket/git-lpdf/src).

Comment: @Habi Thanks for the suggestion. From the command line I do this with `git show SHA1:path/to/file > SHA1.pdf | <pdf viewer> SHA1.pdf`. But I was looking for a gui that did this without having to save or create a new file. @Andrew, thanks, I look forward to seeing, sounds useful, especially the front end to latexdiff part.

Comment: With `git checkout COMMIT file.pdf` only `file.pdf` gets modified in your working tree. Then `git checkout HEAD file.pdf` to reset it.

Comment: @Tudor Follow the bitbucket link above.

Comment: A PDF that is generated from a latex file is the same as a class, jar, exe or other file that is compiled from source. It should not be under version control in the first place. Every time you compile the PDF, it will be marked as changed, even if the latex file hasn't, due to time stamps, etc. If you want to see a specific version of the document, checkout that version's revision and compile it.